# Python 2.7 function with keyword arguments in superclass: how to access from subclass?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, variadic

Are keyword arguments handled somehow specially in inherited methods?

When I call an instance method with keyword arguments from the class it's defined in, all goes well. When I call it from a subclass, Python complains about too many parameters passed.

Here's the example. The "simple" methods don't use keyword args, and inheritance works fine (even for me :-) The "KW" methods use keyword args, and inheritance doesn't work anymore... at least I can't see the difference.

```
class aClass(object):
  def aSimpleMethod(self, show):
    print('show: %s' % show)
  def aKWMethod(self, **kwargs):
    for kw in kwargs:
      print('%s: %s' % (kw, kwargs[kw]))

class aSubClass(aClass):
  def anotherSimpleMethod(self, show):
    self.aSimpleMethod(show)
  def anotherKWMethod(self, **kwargs):
    self.aKWMethod(kwargs)

aClass().aSimpleMethod('this')
aSubClass().anotherSimpleMethod('that')
aClass().aKWMethod(show='this')
```

prints `this`, `that`, and `this`, as I expected. But

```
aSubClass().anotherKWMethod(show='that')
```

throws:

```
TypeError: aKWMethod() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `self.aKWMethod(kwargs)`, you're passing the whole dict of keyword arguments as a single positional argument to the (superclass's) `aKWMethod` method.

Change that to `self.aKWMethod(**kwargs)` and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **kwargs when you call the method, it takes no positional args, just *keyword arguments*:

```
 self.aKWMethod(**kwargs)
```

Once you do, it works fine:

```
In [2]: aClass().aSimpleMethod('this')
   ...: aSubClass().anotherSimpleMethod('that')
   ...: aClass().aKWMethod(show='this')
   ...: 
show: this
show: that
show: this
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to demonstrate in the simplest terms possible what is going wrong, note that this error has nothing to do with inheritance. Consider the following case:

```
>>> def f(**kwargs):
...     pass
...
>>> f(a='test') # works fine!
>>> f('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

The point is that `**kwargs` *only* allows keyword arguments and cannot be replaced by a positional argument.